# UIScrollView inner boundaries issue

Tags: ios

So I have a strange bug in my code that is confusing me...
In the screenshot below, I have a UIScrollView. In the Storyboard, I set the background color to Red. Then using a bit of code, I set the boundaries so that there is a tiny gap between the title bar area and footer (The yellow slivers).

The problem is that when I scroll the scroll view *All* the "bottom", the scroll bar is not actually at the bottom of the UIScrollViews boundaries. This behavior is also mirrored when you scroll all the way to the top of the scrollview, and so it adds an ugly space to the top of the scrollview.

Is there some sort of separate bounds that I should set for the inner size of the scrollview?

[image: Screenshot]
Code:

```
CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

self.productScrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, navBarHeight+22, screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width-footerHeight-navBarHeight-23);    
self.productScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.productScrollview.frame.size.height, self.productScrollview.frame.size.width);
self.productScrollview.contentSize =CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, 700);
```

Comment: Have you tried to fix the constraint from top in storyboard for scrollview?

Comment: @Ashu Yeah, it moves the scroll bar up or down, but the content still has a large gap added on when you scroll all the way up or all the way down.

Comment: have you tried reducing the **height** of _scrollView_ from `700` in your code? is the same height used in the _size inspector_ ?

Comment: @GoGreen Sorry for the late response! Tried several smaller numbers, but still same issue.